# get to the specified parent element and then find the specified child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure

```
<div class="parent_wrapper">
    <div class="child_element_one">
    </div>
    <div class="child_element_two">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="child_element_three">
        <a href="#">Click to test</a>
    </div>
```

and the script that I tried to work with it (my attempt so far)

```
$('.child_element_three a').click(function(e){
    $(this).parents('parent_wrapper').find('.child_element_two p').text("added to the div that has a class of child_element_two paragraph");
});
```

Problem: added to all div that has a class of child_element_two paragraph, what I want is only add text to the .child_element_two paragraph of the same group that has the current triggered link or the current group of the click link. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the class selector in `parent_wrapper`, you have used it as a element selector.

Also change [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents) to [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) since you want only the first parent matching the selector

```
$(this).closest('.parent_wrapper').find('.child_element_two p').text("added to the div that has a class of child_element_two paragraph");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/udzdnh11/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `.siblings` in this task:

```
$('.child_element_three a').click(function (e) {
     $(this).parent().siblings('.child_element_two').find('p').text("added to the div that has a class of child_element_two paragraph");
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/udzdnh11/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.child_element_three a').click(function(e){
     $(this).parents('.parent_wrapper').find('.child_element_two p').text("added to    the div that has a class of child_element_two paragraph");
 });
```

U missing the`.` in `parents('.parent_wrapper')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$('.child_element_three a').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().find('.child_element_two p').text("added to the div that has a class of child_element_two paragraph");
});
```